# Does "full count" in MLB mean to "three balls and two strikes"

Tags: mlb

At about 7'11″ into the video linked below, the announcer says "full count now three balls and two"

[Boston Red Sox vs New York Yankees - August 2, 2020 - Regular Season 2020 - MLB - Full Game](https://youtu.be/ozt-dmWGkek)

Does "full count" in MLB mean to "three balls and two strikes"? Is it in the statistical?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_(baseball)#Full_count):

> A full count [...] is the common name for a count where the batter has three balls and two strikes.